# JAVA POO ¿Cómo utilizar un for each para hacer un recorrido en mi lista e imprimirlos?

Tags: java, array, poo

Tengo mi clase `lista` donde coloque mis propiedades, las cuales son:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Lista {

    private String posicion;
    private String numeroParte;
    private String descripcion;
    private double monto;
    private String cambioPrecio;
    private String concepto;
    private double montoConvenio;

    public ArrayList<Lista> ListaConceptos = new ArrayList<Lista>();  

    public Lista(String posicion, String numeroParte, String descripcion, double monto, String cambioPrecio, String concepto, double montoConvenio){

     this.posicion = posicion;
     this.numeroParte = numeroParte;
     this.descripcion = descripcion;
     this.monto = monto;
     this.cambioPrecio = cambioPrecio;
     this.concepto = concepto;
     this.montoConvenio = montoConvenio;

    }


    public String getPosicion() {
     return posicion;
    }

    public String getNumeroParte() {
     return numeroParte;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
     return descripcion;
    }

    public double getMonto() {
     return monto;
    }

    public String getCambioPrecio() {
     return cambioPrecio;
    }

    public String getConcepto() {
     return concepto;
    }

    public double getMontoConvenio() {
     return montoConvenio;
    }

}
```

Y tengo un objeto donde se irán almacenando los datos, el cual es:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ListaConcepto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<Lista> lstA = new ArrayList<Lista>();

Lista ObjPintura = new Lista("Hola", "Testing", "Navidad", 25.25, "Kyrie", "mua", 25);
lstA.add(ObjPintura);

    }

}
```

Como podría crear un método para que me imprima esos datos con for each?

gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que necesitas es llevar el Objeto a String, en ese caso debieras sobrescribir la función toString que todo Objeto tiene en Java 
Ex de tu Clase Lista:

```
public String toString(){
    return "Lista: { posicion: "+this.posicion+", "+"numeroParte: "+this.numeroParte+", "+"descripcion: "+this.descripcion+", "+"monto: "+this.monto+", "+"cambioPrecio: "+this.cambioPrecio+", "+"concepto: "+this.concepto+", "+"montoConvenio: "+this.montoConvenio+"}; ";
}
```

y luego realizar una iteración sobre la Lista por Ex:

```
for( Lista lis :lstA ){
    System.out.println(lis.toString());
}
```

o también con [forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) desde Java 8

```
lstA.forEach((list) -> {
    System.out.println(list.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo según tu código:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ListaConcepto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<Lista> lstA = new ArrayList<Lista>();

        Lista ObjPintura = new Lista("Hola", "Testing", "Navidad", 25.25, "Kyrie", "mua", 25);
        lstA.add(ObjPintura);

        //Opcion 1
        for(Lista elemento : lstA) {
            System.out.println("Posicion: "+elemento.getPosicion()+", "+" NumeroParte: "+elemento.getNumeroParte()+", "+" Descripcion: "+elemento.getDescripcion()+", "+" Monto: "+elemento.getMonto()+", "+" CambioPrecio: "+elemento.getCambioPrecio()+", "+" Concepto: "+elemento.getConcepto()+", "+" MontoConvenio: "+elemento.getMontoConvenio());
        }

        //Opcion 2
        for(int i=0; i < lstA.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Posicion: "+lstA.get(i).getPosicion()+", "+" NumeroParte: "+lstA.get(i).getNumeroParte()+", "+" Descripcion: "+lstA.get(i).getDescripcion()+", "+" Monto: "+lstA.get(i).getMonto()+", "+" CambioPrecio: "+lstA.get(i).getCambioPrecio()+", "+" Concepto: "+lstA.get(i).getConcepto()+", "+" MontoConvenio: "+lstA.get(i).getMontoConvenio());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: siempre considera añadir una explicación al código para que no sea marcada tu respuesta de baja calidad